# Determining if a TransactionScope is committed or not

Tags: .net, sql-server, ado.net, transactionscope

Using .net 2 and ADO.NET.

Is there a way to determine if a transaction is committed or not? The reason is that I'm stuck with a legacy framework that I cannot alter and there might or might not be an ambient transaction. Sometimes the ambient transaction is already committed causing the next database call to throw an exception and I need to know if it is or not.

Any pointers would be great!

Thanks

Johan

Comment: Posting some examples of the current codebase would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation.Status`. If it is anything other than `TransactionStatus.Active`, you should not be using the current transaction.

It goes without saying that you should check `Transaction.Current` for `null` before taking its status.

Answer (score 3):

The best method I've found for capturing this most efficiently / correctly is as follows:

Inside the transactionscope using statement, and before the call to scope/Complete().

```
//Register for the transaction completed event for the current transaction
Transaction.Current.TransactionCompleted += new TransactionCompletedEventHandler(Current_TransactionCompleted);
```

Then create the event handler function as follows:

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the TransactionCompleted event of the Current control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.Transactions.TransactionEventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
static void Current_TransactionCompleted(object sender, TransactionEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Transaction.TransactionInformation.Status == TransactionStatus.Committed)
    {
        /// Yay it's committed code goes here!
    }
}
```

To quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.transactioncompleted.aspx)

"You can register for this event instead of using a volatile enlistment to get outcome information for transactions. The parameter passed to the TransactionCompletedEventHandler delegate is a Transaction instance. You can then query the TransactionInformation property of the specific instance to get an instance of TransactionInformation, whose Status property contains the status of a transaction with either the Committed or Aborted value."